# Symbol not found, Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, installation, cython

I have a huge `gl.pxd` file with all the definitions of `gl.h`, `glu.h` and `glut.h`. For example it has these lines:

```
cdef extern from '<OpenGL/gl.h>':
    ctypedef unsigned int GLenum
    cdef void glBegin( GLenum mode )
```

I have a `window.pyx` file, which looks like this:

```
# Import OpenGL definitions
# headers of gl, glu and glut
from gl cimport *

cdef int argcp
cdef char **argv

cdef void render_scene():

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )

    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES )
    glVertex2f( -.5, -.5)
    glVertex2f( .5, 0 )
    glVertex2f( 0, -5. )
    glEnd()

    glutSwapBuffers()

cpdef main():
    # Initialize GLUT and create Window
    glutInit( &argcp, argv )
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE )
    glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 100 )
    glutInitWindowSize( 1280, 720 )
    glutCreateWindow( 'My Shiny New Window' )

    # Register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc( render_scene )

    # Enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop()
```

I also have a `setup.py` which looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension('window', ['window.pyx'])]
)
```

Which I call with `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` and it compiles, and the output is this:

```
running build_ext
cythoning window.pyx to window.c
building 'window' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -c window.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/window.o
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/window.o -o /Users/petervaro/cygl/window.so
```

And I have a `window_test.py` which looks like this:

```
import window
window.main()
```

But if I want to run this python snippet I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/petervaro/cygl/window_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import window
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/petervaro/cygl/window.so, 2): Symbol not found: _glBegin
  Referenced from: /Users/petervaro/cygl/window.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/petervaro/cygl/window.so
```

My problem is really similar to this one:
[What is the meaning of this ImportError when importing a Cython generated .so file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7068721/2188562) -- although afaik I don't have an external library, I want to use the *builtin* OpenGL lib...

Oh, and I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5, Cython 19.2 and Python 3.3.
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though OpenGL and GLUT are on the system (*builtins*) I have to link them as frameworks in the compilation process, so the `setup.py` should look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

exts = Extension( name='window',
                  sources=['window.pyx'],
                  extra_link_args=['-framework', 'OpenGL', '-framework', 'GLUT'])

setup( name='cygl',
       ext_modules = cythonize( exts ))
```