# Building graph-tool on OSX with Python 3.4

Tags: python, macos, python-3.4, graph-tool

I tried to install graph-tool on Mac OSX 10.10 using homebrew. The brew build process works fine, but when I try to import graph-tool I get [the error described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411447/graph-tool-crahes-on-import). 
Another problem with homebrew is that I always builds graph-tool for python2.7 and it installs the packages in the Python 2.7 sit-packages folder. But I want to use it with Python 3.4. These are the reasons why I tried to build graph-tool from source.

The `./configure` command automatically uses Python 2.7, too. So I passed it the desired Python version with `./configure PYTHON=python3.4`

It then detects the correct version as well as the related paths but crash with the following error:

> configure: error:
>   Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the
>   main Python library has been   installed in some non-standard library
>   path. If so, pass it to configure,   via the LDFLAGS environment
>   variable.
>   Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
>
> ======================================================================
>   ERROR! 
>   You probably have to install the development version of the
>   Python package for your distribution. The exact name of this package varies 
>   among them.
>
> ======================================================================

The error occurs with and without `PYTHON` variable set.
From the output of `./configure` I can see that everything works fine except for the last line, which says:

> checking consistency of all components of python development
>   environment... no

Whats does the above line mean and how do I properly install graph-tool on my maschine?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is explaining *exactly* what needs to be done. Since python was installed in a non-standard path, you need to pass the flag `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"` pointing to the directory where the python libraries are located. This is most likely `"/usr/local/lib"`, if you are using homebrew.

Comment: I tried to set the LDFLAGS before posting this question, but unfortunately it had no effect.

Comment: Then you probably did not pass the correct path. Look inside the config.log file to see the actual error.

Comment: Did not help me either. It would seem option `-u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` to gcc is what is causing it to choke but have no idea how to fix this

Comment: One year has passed and I still keep getting the same error message, which tells me to pass the "non-standard" Python libs directory, even  though I passed the *exact* location.

Comment: This does not work. One possible source of error is that configure's `checking for python3.4` results in
`/Users/username/.virtualenvs/graph-tool/bin/python`, while `checking for Python include path` results in `-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m`. The same for the `lib`. This likely creates consistency problems.

Comment: @MaxPowers any luck with that? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've just checked it once again on another machine and with Python3.6. configure automatically take Python2.7. When passing `PYTHON="python3"` it *correctly* detects all paths for Python3 but then throws the same old error message. Passing `LIBS="-L/path/to/python"` results in the same error.

Comment: I also updated `autoconf`, `automake`, and `pkg-config` as suggested by @ostrokach. Did not help. I could the exclude the behaviour @L.C.Leitão mentioned. Configure detects all path correctly.

Comment: It is very hard to troubleshoot this without proper debug information, such as the *full* output of configure, config.log, etc. The snippets you provided do not contain useful information.

Comment: @MaxPowers I found that I had to pass the variable PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS, as I explain in detail in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I was trying to install `graph-tool` using outdated an `autoconf` / `automake` / `pkg-config` combination (installed using `yum` in CentOS 5.10). Installing those packages from source fixed the problem... although I'm not sure how this related to my python installation....

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by passing the variable `PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,-stack_size,1000000 -F/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks -framework CoreFoundation"`.
In your case, it would be the path to the `homebrew` installation of `python3.4`.
The way I found out is that in the `config.log`, the error message shows the following:

```
configure:19023: checking python extra libraries
configure:19030: result: -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation 
configure:19037: checking python extra linking flags
configure:19044: result: -Wl,-stack_size,1000000  -framework CoreFoundation Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
configure:19051: checking consistency of all components of python development environment
configure:19079: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -F/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/ -Wl,-stack_size,1000000  -framework CoreFoundation Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python conftest.c  -L/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib -lpython3.6m -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation  -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation  >&5
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python'
```

The error seems to be path `'Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python'`, that in a `homebrew` installation does not exist. I search for the same path in the `config.log` and I found this line:

```
PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,-stack_size,1000000 -framework CoreFoundation Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python"
```

So, the solution for me was to pass this variable with the right path.